# Unable to manipulate DOM content of Ionic Android app

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

```
angular.module("app.categories").controller("CategoryController", t),  t.$inject = ["$scope", "$stateParams", "$state", "categoryManager"]

angular.module("app", ["ionic", ["app.home","app.products",...]);
angular.module("app").run(["$templateCache", function(t) {
t.put("app/scripts/about/about.html", '<ion- view>.....'),t.put("app/scripts/home/block.html", '<div>....')}]); //this is how the page content is loaded
```

I am running this app in the browser using Ionic ('Ionic serve' in the root directory). I am not able to run basic JavaScript on the page who's content has been loaded like this. After a timeout if DOMContentLoaded is called, the element is picked up but running the following only manipulated the id of element, not the html or the value

```
  setTimeout(function(){
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
            document.getElementById('customBox').id = 'changed'; //to test, id changes
            document.getElementById('customBox').innerHtml = '<h1> test </h1>'; //does not change anything, no errors in console
            document.getElementById('customBox').text= '<h1> test </h1>'; //does not change anything, no errors in console
            document.getElementById('customBox').html= '<h1> test </h1>'; //does not change anything, no errors in console

});

},2000);
```

Is there anything that's preventing any change to the page content in the browser? How to make changes in the DOM content using simple JavaScript for this Ionic Android app?

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to manipulate the html of an angular app directly unless you have written a custom directive. If you want to change the `innerHtml` use `ng-bind-html` on the div and just modify your scope.

Also, don't use `setTimeout` in an angular app, always use the `$timeout` or `$interval` services instead.

So your code, somewhere inside a controller, should just look like this:

```
$scope.testContent = '<h1> tet </h1>';
```

and the html:

```
<div id='customBox' ng-bind-html="testContent"></div>
```

Although the main reason your code doesn't work is that as soon as you've changed the id to "changed" all the other `getElementById` calls won't find the div.

Comment: Trying with the $timeout, regarding the id change, that was just to test that at least something related to the element changes, the same thing happens even after i remove the id change, the rest of them don't change anything

Answer (score 0):

Try using angular.element like this

```
angular.element( document.getElementById('customBox') ).innerHtml = '<h1> test </h1>';
```

Visit this link for detail https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element